# un expected Operand type clash: table type is incompatible with int while executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, listbox

I have Table valued Parameter like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Loc] AS TABLE(Lo integer)
```

My Stored Proceurdure taking location Id like this:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary] 
 @startDate datetime,  
 @endDate datetime,
@locations dbo.Loc readonly
..........................
.........................
WHERE     (Transaction_tbl.dtime BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate) 
AND  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @locations WHERE lo = Location_tbl.Locid)
```

my locid field is integer this locid coming from my listbox.if i select one item 1 locid will come.if i select 2 item 2 locid will come.. I've got a ListBox which populates the @locations parameter (an integer), I took my listbox value like this

```
cnt = LSTlocations.SelectedItems.Count
  Dim dtlist As New DataTable()
    Dim locid As Integer
    If cnt > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To cnt - 1
            dtlist.Columns.Add(locid, GetType(Integer))
            Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
            locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
            dtlist.Rows.Add(locid)
        Next
End If
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd23 As New SqlCommand("T_TransactionSummary", con.connect)
        cmd23.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim tvp1 As SqlParameter = cmd23.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locations", dtlist)
         tvp1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
         tvp1.TypeName = "dbo.Loc"
        da.SelectCommand = cmd23
        da.Fill(ds)
```

but i am getting error like this:

> Operand type clash: table type is incompatible with int

What is wrong with my code and stored procedure

Comment: possible duplicate of [operand type clash table type is incompatible with int while passing parameter to stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615532/operand-type-clash-table-type-is-incompatible-with-int-while-passing-parameter-t)

Comment: sir,,i haven't got answer of this question..please

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because you didn't specify the first two parameters (@startdate, @enddate) for your stored procedure when you create your SqlCommand